# How to copy up to the cursor without including the charater under the cursor

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Like you would in virtually any application editing text.
For example:

```
this is a big sentence so I can explain
^                         ^
start of selection        my cursor is here
```

I'd like to copy only up to the cursor but not including I.

Any way to do this?

Comment: I suggest go through `$ vimtutor`. Otherwise you're gonna keep getting in many of same problems. These are very trivial actions, so, you really need to read the manuals. Start with `vimtutor`, go through `:h intro.txt`.

Comment: Welcome to our site @ LukeSkywalker! I'm undeleting the question because @Klaus put some effort in the answer and the question isn't bad or off topic so there is no reason to make them loose their answer

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**: `y^`

**Explanation**

vim is a modal editor. That means it has specific modes for doing specific things. Most common three modes are:

1. Normal Mode : Enter all normal editor commands (see `:h Normal-mode`)
2. Insert Mode : Insert characters (see `:h Insert-mode`
3. Visual Mode : Highlight a text area to perform a normal editor comman on (see `:h Visual-mode`

But there are many other modes also. For more info, see `:h intro.txt`

In normal mode, you can perform editing tasks, for example, yanking (a.k.a copying) text. You can do that by two methods:

- **Normal mode** : You need to perform `:h Operator-pending-mode` to yank the portion of the text you want to. Vim has many text objects (see `:h motion.txt`). You can go in operator-pending mode by issuing a command, in this case, yank (<kbd>y</kbd>) and then specify the text object to perform the command (yank) on with suitable text objects.
  If you want to yank from the start of the line til the character under the cursor, I'd do `y^`
- **Visual mode** : You go into visual mode with <kbd>v</kbd> and highlight the portion of the text you want to perform the yank command on, and then issue the command. I'd do `hv^y`

Comment: I am sorry, for some reason the wrong version of my question was posted... My question was more precise.

Comment: What do you mean? I see that you edited your question, but my answer does apply to your edited (and more specific and explained) question. If the answer doesn't fulfill your requirements, i.e. doesn't solve your problem, please report back.

Comment: I believe if I follow your instruction I will copy the selection *including* the character under the cursor. Which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @LukeSkywalker But it is working as you want in my vim. Can you confirm that you issue the command `y^` when your cursor is on the character you want to exclude from the yanked text?

Comment: @LukeSkywalker `Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'` let's say my cursor is on the hyphen of `vim-fugitive` and then I issue `y^`. It should yank the text of `Plug 'tpope/vim` and you can check what is yanked in the default unnamed register by `:reg"`

Comment: well it works thanks to 'h'. But this is not what I am looking for. Let's say you've selected a whole line, and your cursor is on the first character of the next line. Pressing h is not going to bring the cursor at the end of the previous line. I want to do this because I am mapping Ctrl+c so that vim behave like any other editor.

Comment: Oh, you're already in visual-mode? Then you need to edit your question, it's not properly explained. If you can, you could add a GIF of what you want.